# Erlang disappeared from /usr/bin/erl

Tags: 14.04, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, erlang

## The setting

I have downloaded [rabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) and used it on an EC2 14.04 machine for a few days.

The setting was simple - I downloaded the [Binary .tar.gz](https://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html), opened it, and typed:

```
sbin/rabbitmq-server
```

RabbitMQ started and everything worked fine.

## The problem

When I opened the machine this morning and tried to start rabbitMQ the same way, I got:

```
ubuntu rabbitmq-server: erl: not found
```

## What have I tried

First, I was looking for `erl`:

```
$ locate erl | grep "erl$" | grep -v perl
/usr/bin/erl
/usr/bin/run_erl
/usr/bin/to_erl
/usr/share/doc/erlang-xmerl
```

But:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/erl
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/erl: No such file or directory
```

This means that `erlang` was there a few hours ago, before the last update of `locate`, but was somehow deleted!

I have re-installed erlang using `apt-get` and everything works well.

## The question

**Why was erlang deleted from my machine? How can I prevent this from happening in the future?**

Comment: you could make the file immutable by using `chattr +i`, but then you'd need to make it mutable each time Erlang was to be updated.  I don't remember if the root user can modify immutable files without first making them mutable or not.